# Binding click event in aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a component ButtonHtml that intercepts click events so that it can publish the event to a component that prevents clicking on something more than once to keep from double-clicking. It was working prior to upgrading the aurelia-framework.

Now I get this error. I'm not sure why.

> ButtonHtml.js:51 TypeError: this.click is not a function
>       at ButtonHtml.buttonClick (ButtonHtml.js:47)
>       at CallScope.evaluate (aurelia-binding.js:1542)
>       at Listener.callSource (aurelia-binding.js:5119)
>       at Listener.handleEvent (aurelia-binding.js:5128)

Here is the Html and JS

```
<template>
    <button class="${class} waves-effect btn btn-${isSelected ? 'selected' : type} ${isBlock ? 'btn-block' : ''}" click.trigger="buttonClick()" title="${title}" disabled.bind="disabled">
        <span class.bind="labelVisibility === '' ? '' : labelVisibility" if.bind="label !== ''">${label}</span>
        <i if.bind="icon !== ''" class="material-icons ${label !== '' ? iconLocation : ''}">${icon}</i>
    </button>
</template>

import {bindable, bindingMode, containerless, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {EventPublishingService} from '../../Service/EventServices/EventPublishingService';

@containerless()
@inject(EventPublishingService)
export class ButtonHtml
{
    constructor(eventPublishingService)
    {
        this.eventPublishingService = eventPublishingService;
    }

    /**
     * Style bindings
     */
    @bindable label = '';
    @bindable labelVisibility = '';

    @bindable icon = '';
    @bindable iconLocation= 'left';

    @bindable class = '';
    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) type = 'primary';    
    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) isSelected = false;
    @bindable isBlock = false;
    @bindable disabled = false;

    /**
     * Events
     */
    @bindable click;

    /**
     * Native properties
     */
    @bindable title = '';
    @bindable isBlocking = false;

    buttonClick()
    {
        if (this.isBlocking)
        {
            this.eventPublishingService.disableActions();
        }        

        try{
            this.click();
        }
        catch(exception)
        {
            console.error(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a typical use:

```
<button-html type="action" icon="done" label="OK" tap.call="Go()"></button-html>
```

Here are the aurelia library versions

> "aurelia-animator-css": "1.0.3", "aurelia-bootstrapper": "2.1.1",
>   "aurelia-dialog": "1.0.0-rc.1.0.3", "aurelia-fetch-client": "1.1.3",
>   "aurelia-framework": "1.1.5", "aurelia-materialize-bridge": "~0.31.0",
>   "aurelia-pal-browser": "1.3.0", "aurelia-polyfills": "1.2.2",
>   "aurelia-router": "1.4.0", "aurelia-templating": "1.5.0",
>   "aurelia-templating-binding": "1.4.0", "aurelia-templating-resources":
>   "1.5.1", "aurelia-templating-router": "1.2.0", "aurelia-validation":
>   "1.1.2",

Edit:

Got it working by changing the usage to click.call instead of tap.call

```
<button-html type="action" icon="done" label="OK" click.call="Go()"></button-html>
```

Comment: Without seeing how you are using this custom element, it's hard to know exactly what's happening.

Comment: I'll edit the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bindable for `click`, but you aren't binding anything to it. It looks like you're binding to `tap`, but that isn't a bindable you've set up. I'd probably lean against using `click` as a bindable name as that might cause confusion with the build in `click` event on all HTML elements.

Just change the name of the bindable to `tap` and it should start working as expected.

Comment: Tried it. It didn't work. tap is a custom attribute using hammerjs so that the button works better on ipads. This was all working before the upgrade.

Comment: Well, you're trying to call a function on your VM that is undefined, that's why you're getting an exception thrown. You'll need to bind in something to `click` for everything to work.

Comment: The custom tap attribute is where it gets bound to click.

Comment: You were right about needing to bind to click. Thanks.